# Exclusive "from" or "to"

Tags: word-usage, adjectives

If I want to let a customer know that she/he can only buy spare parts from us, and put this into legal documents by using the word "exclusive", which proposition should I use?  "from", "to" or something else?

The sentence I have in my mind is:

> All spare parts shall be exclusive from [our company name].

Will the meaning be different if I change the preposition "from" to "to"?

Is this correct? Or is there other ways to express it still using the word "exclusive"?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is asking for contract legalese wording, which is beyond the scope of this site.

Comment: Thanks for the help.  I am sorry for the errors.  English is a foreign language to me.

Comment: If English is a foreign language to you, you may wish to look at our sister site [ell.se]. As an aside, I don't know where you are doing business, but I think that (except in restricted circumstances) such a condition would be illegal and unenforceable under English law.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't express your idea, but rather the reverse.

You should write :

"All spare parts shall exclusively be bought from / provided by [X]"

Comment: The position of the _exclusively_ is also important. The way you ordered its words, the sentence means _All spare parts acquired from [X] shall exclusively be bought (and not received free of charge or stolen, in which case they cannot be considered spare parts as defined by this contract)._ That'd be one strange provision, but that's the meaning of that sentence. So, with the correct word order:
_All spare parts shall be bought/provided exclusively from/by [X]._

Comment: @TaliaFord +1 for commenting on the word order, but the same thing could be conveyed slightly more concisely by "shall be *obtained* exclusively from us" (subject to be comment above about legality!).